# About once in the 500th user sends GET requests instead of POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, get

We use the following AjaxSetup:

```
$.ajaxSetup(
{
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: "{}",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; charset=utf-8" },
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, options)
    {
        if ( options.contentType == "application/json" && typeof options.data != "string" )
            options.data = JSON.stringify(options.data);
    },
    processData: false
});
```

And I send my post requests with the following:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: '/url',
    data: postData,
    success: function(json) 
    {
    }
})
```

We work with ASP.NET, and these defaults work in general perfectly well. Everything is automatically synced to JSON, and are read properly and modelbinded in our ASP.NET pipeline.

Only once in about a thousand some users seem to have problems. Instead of a `POST` request, their client sends `GET` requests.

The UserAgent mentions Chrome 37.0.2062.120 on Windows 7.

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36`

What reasons could it be this client is sending GET requests?

- Could this be caused by an adblocker?
- or firewall settings?
- What other settings could I trace to investigate further?

Comment: Perhaps one of your user is a troll :) Have you tried tracert + wireshark?

Comment: Get same specifications browser, get to the point where you send via `get` instead of `post`, repeat same few times. If it's repeating, than it may be bug in browser. Can you use accept both GET and POST methods? REQUEST?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just someone going to `/url` manually?  That would invoke a get.

Comment: I see which user it is, and I'm pretty sure it's not a troll ;) because I need to send quite a (complicated) json payload it's not a get request.

Comment: No the behaviour shows, that he just tries to submit it, and it fails and then he tries again, tries again, etc. I'm pretty sure it must be something in the configuration at the client.

Comment: One other thing that I might suspect is a cross domain issue between the www.domain.com and the domain.com ... but also that should 'in theory' not be possible, because I only use relative urls.

Comment: @briansol. I'm pretty sure. The url is nowhere visible, and the behaviour shows that he is just trying to resubmit a failed ajax call, and I even see a part of the payload in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

What is expected return `Boolean` of `typeof options.data != "string"` ? Appear that condition would return `false` ? ; possibly sending an empty object to server - even if at `$.ajax()` a proper object is included

i.e.g,

Try

```
var postData = {"def":789};
$.ajaxSetup(
{
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: "{}",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; charset=utf-8" },
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, options)
    {
         if ( options.contentType == "application/json" && typeof options.data != "string" )
            options.data = JSON.stringify(options.data);
            console.log(typeof options.data
            , typeof options.data != "string"
            , typeof options.data !== "string") // `string` , `false`, `false`
    },
    processData: false
});
$.ajax("", postData);
```

if some way the `processData` option is altered to `true` , the request would become a `GET` request , and possibly return an `error`.

Tried without `$.ajaxSetup()` `data` wrapped in quotes , or , cast as `string` ?

As the `beforeSend` would evaluate

`data: "{}"`

as `string` and return `false` ?

See `network` tab at `console` ; where `postData` (object, `Request Payload`) is rendered as `{}` : no data; no data sent to server.

See http://api.jQuery.com/jquery.ajax

> processData (default: true) Type: Boolean By default, data passed in
>   to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a
>   string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting
>   to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If
>   you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this
>   option to false.